# Is there a way to do background substraction on video of moving cameras? based on optical flow mainly?

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, image-segmentation, opticalflow

My problem is: Now i can get the dense optical flow for the video. The object and background are moving at the same time due to the rotation of the camera, therefore both the target and backgroud have OF results. Looking for a way to eliminate backgrounds.

1.The camera I'm using rotates at a fix speed when recording. Is there any way to relate the velocity of the camera to the OF of the background? So i can tell background flow from foreground flow based on the parameter of the camera? Is depth informaton necessary?
2.The camera(event camera) i'm using outputs binary images, which makes it harder to tell when target and background mixed up.

I tried put a threshold for the optical flow for all the pixels. That is, mask off all the pixels that have relatively low OF values. But the problem is when the target(a small drone) is moving slowly, this doesn't work, and this method can't eliminate all backgrounds.

Comment: bgsub is a category of low level algorithms. the only hope of getting traction with those on your video material is to employ camera tracking (SfM/SLAM), which is a seriously more expensive algorithm. it's like getting an arduino to do a weird trick by soldering a $2000 nvidia gpu to it. -- you'd help _yourself_ by showing some data. -- assuming no translation between cam and scene, distances become irrelevant. this might be tractable with just optical flow... which could be just a component in tracking of scene features for SfM/SLAM ordinarily

Comment: Thanks for answering! i 'd look into some  SLAM materials then. New field again...@Christoph Rackwitz

Answer (score 1):

*Background subtraction* is a category of *low level* algorithms. Don't expect too much out of that. You'll have to deploy some computationally expensive operations. You'll basically have to **stabilize** the footage like it were an action cam.

Assuming no translation between cam and scene, distances become irrelevant. That leaves just rotation to compensate for. That is less of a headache.

You'll have to track the camera rotation/pose. That topic is called Structure from Motion or SLAM. Optical flow can be a component in that. Usually it involves feature tracking. That can be done via matching, or via sparse optical flow on the feature points.

A good approach would probably combine both (sensor fusion). Optical flow is fairly low-noise but when you accumulate it, it'll drift. The feature matching is noisy but doesn't drift.

When you know how your camera moves, you can then warp the image into the initial (or any other) camera pose. By "camera pose" I mean projection. It's really just a specific orientation of your projection. The math for this is commonly discussed in "image stitching".